# String binary combinatorics

Tags: c++, string, binary, combinatorics

Is there a simple way to find all binary strings whose digits add up to a value of x points, assuming that all ones are worth 2 points, and all zeros are worth 1 point. Let me explain:

Considering that I receive a number 5, how could I get all possible strings such that 2*(number of ones) + 1*zeros = 5. 
*All results for 5 down:*

00000

10000

0100

0010

0001

101

110

011

(I do know that the number of possible solutions is the fibonacci number of 5+1 (x+1), but I cannot think of a way to find all values).

I was thinking of adding numbers in binary or maybe using a base converter, but I may be missing something here. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Just find all binary strings and check if they satisfies? Or use recursion?

Comment: Generating strings with necessary 0s and 1s is trivial (in your case it is "00000" "0001" and "011"), then you can use `std::next_permutation` to generate variants

Comment: Yes... there are a loooot of ways, pick one you want. If you're still stuck, come back here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By a single loop you can generate base strings (in your case "00000", "0001" and "011") then use `std::next_permutation()`:

```
for( int zeros = n; zeros >= 0; zeros -= 2 ) {
    int ones = ( n - zeros ) / 2;
    std::string base = std::string( zeros, '0' ) + std::string( ones, '1' );
}
```

[live example](https://ideone.com/faNU5m)

Comment: ⁺1 It's a surprisingly simple and concise solution. :)

Comment: @Jarod42 sorry, I fixed bug here but not on ideone, it should be `zeros >= 0`, updated

Answer (score 0):

Try sth like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

void getSums(int sum, std::vector<std::string>& results, std::string currSum) {
    if (0 == sum) {
        results.emplace_back(currSum.c_str());
        return;
    } else if (sum < 0) {
        return;
    } else {
        getSums(sum-2, results, currSum+"1");
        getSums(sum-1, results, currSum+"0");
    }
}

std::vector<std::string> getAllSums(int sum) {
    std::vector<std::string> results;
    std::string currSum;
    getSums(sum, results, currSum);
    return results;
}

int main() {
    std::vector<std::string> res = getAllSums(5);
    for (std::string& r : res) {
        std::cout << r << std::endl;
    }

}
```

Or switch to DP and cache results.